# iOS Round corner of button

Tags: ios, button, rounded-corners

I've been out of pocket for 11 months because of a health glitch. Did I read somewhere that I can specify a corner by selecting "Large, "Medium," or "Small"? I know how to do it via the layer property, but if there's an easier way, I'd like to use it.

Was I dreaming, or can somebody point me in the right direction?

TIA

Comment: If you're targeting iOS 15+ you can take advantage of  [UIButton.Configuration.CornerStyle](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/configuration/cornerstyle)

Comment: @DonMag exactly what I was looking for! And it has all the other characteristics I might need. Gracias!